# Is there a "right" way to make the setupController hook fire consistently?

Tags: ember.js

I have a page with a search bar.  Upon entering text and clicking enter, a transition occurs to the same page with a query in the URL (ie .../search/banana).  Due to the way the model and setupController hooks fire, I have set up my code as follows:

**model:** Updates the search text field with the text that was passed, */and changes the controller's model to the current JavaScript timestamp as a hack to make sure Ember calls setupController/*.

**setupController:** obtains the text from the search field, and should then update the model with the proper search results.

What I'm doing in the model hook is a hack, but I'm not sure how else to do this in a way that remains consistent with my URL requirement (the search should work whether somebody manually enters an appropriate URL, or a transitionTo occurred)

I'd appreciate it if somebody could tell me if there's a "right" way to ensure that setupController is called regardless of whether or not Ember thinks that the model has changed (which seems to be the culprit that's currently necessitating the hack.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't use setupController myself, but if the search bar is used on entire application, you should define this on ApplicationController. If not, you can define it in your controller.

Application template:

```
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="searchKeyword" action="doSearch"}}
```

App.js:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    searchKeyword: '',
    actions: {
        doSearch: function()
        {
           var keyword = this.get('searchKeyword');
           // do your logic here
        }
    }
});
```

When user hit enter, it will trigger doSearch action and you can just

```
this.get('model').filter()
```

or any logic you want.

Comment: This completely ignores my requirement that the search state is evident in the URL and using that URL results in that search state.  And that's not the problem, the functionality is all there, and it all works.  It just feels hacky.  What I'd like is for setupController to always run, even if the model doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

@dgbonomo, I think your existing approach is great.  From an Ember point of view your model *is* changing each time that a new search happens.  Think of the query as the main model, and the search results as a collection of models that "belong" to the query.